# Java finalize method ,SocksSocketImpl, Profiling and others

Tags: java, linux, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, finalizer

We have a batch job, that reads data from database and writes it to a file. The job is written on top of Spring Batch 2.8. We have noticed, it's taking a lot of memory and are trying to tune it. I have some questions while performing the exercise

1. I know implementing finalize() is not recommended. In numerous posts I have read - they say the object might be pushed to a ReferenceQueue and a Finalizer thread polls the queue. So is there a way, I can check the queue myself? (I know a memory dump will show this, but sometimes the file is too huge to transfer from a live system to a local machine and perform diagnostics).
2. What exactly is the difference between a trivial and non-trivial finalize() method? Couldn't find an article which explains this.
3. If finalize() method is not a good idea, why does AbstractPlainSocketImpl,FileInputStream and others implement it? And how is that, their finalize method helps them in GC and not to be part of unreachable or dead code?
4. While using jvisualvm or jmc - the committed heap size is shown as 600MB. But when I execute the below command on our Linux environment it shows me the memory as 800MB+.

   ```
   ps --cols 500 -C java -o user,ppid,pid,pcpu,rss,size,vsize,cmd | grep <uid> | awk '{ print $3,$4,$5/1024}'
   ```

Environment Details

```
    Number of cores: 2
    OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5
    Total Physical Memory: 7.69GB
    JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_45-b18)
    JVM Command Line Arguments: -Xloggc:../logs/Job-gc.log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:-PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=5M -XX:-CITime -XX:-PrintClassHistogram -XX:-PrintConcurrentLocks -XX:-PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:-TraceClassLoading -XX:-TraceClassUnloading -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7091 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=server.com

    Garbage Collector used (this info is from JMC): ParallelScavenge for Young and ParallelOld for Old.
```

Comment: *What exactly is the difference between a trivial and non-trivial finalize() method? Couldn't find an article which explains this.* - The difference is for *trivial* finalizers, a new instance of `java.lang.ref.Finalizer` is not created for each instance (of the class which has a *trivial* finalizer). If a class defines a *non-trivial* finalize method, for each instance of that class, an instance of `java.lang.ref.Finalizer` is created which is directly referred by java.lang.Finalizer class (keeping the instane of Finalizer alive). See [this](http://www.fasterj.com/articles/finalizer2.shtml).

Comment: As far as point 3 is concerned, `finalze()` implementation of `FileInputStream` and `AbstractPlainSocketImpl` are just backup calls to clean up / close opened resources in case the user fails to do that. Note, `finalize()` might never be called. That code is present to ensure clsoing of underlying streams so that you will not have any deadlock / blocking.

Comment: @TheLostMind Thank You for pointing to the article. I have got a better sense on Finalizer.

Answer (score 0):

> I know a memory dump will show this, but sometimes the file is too huge to transfer from a live system to a local machine and perform diagnostics

Command `tar -czf dump.tar.gz dump.hprof` may help you to transfer that big file.

3GB -> 100MB.

The compress rate of dump file would be so great.